# Haystack EdgeNgramField exact match

Tags: django-haystack

I am using haystack with whoosh backend.  And set up a EdgeNgramField. But when i search for word colored it includes the results for word one-colored too.

```
class TagIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True)
    name = indexes.EdgeNgramField( model_attr='name')
    name_tr = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='name_tr')

    def get_model(self):
        return Tag
```

I have tried adding double quotes but the results are the same.

How can i get exact matches. Do i need to write custom search query?

Comment: Having the same issue and wondering if you ever found a solution?

Comment: No, I could not find.